# Calendars malfunctioning in Spring '13 release?

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce-id, api-27

In the sandboxes i've tested that have the Spring '13 release, I think there's a bug when the user creates an event in either the public or personal calendar.

I navigate to the calendar, double click to add an event on the **day view**, and some of the picklists  don't have values (all none).  However when the user goes to click on the 'new event' btn, those values populate. this is impacting all users in our sandbox, regardless of profile/record type

I wanted to see if any other orgs are having this issue?

Comment: HA! That might explain my problems with http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/empty-picklists-when-account-is-dragged-to-calendar-to-quickly-create-event Damn... My sandbox is on cs7. Production (eu1) works, ditto with my dev. edition (na5). Can't refresh anythong at the moment though to verify if it's fixable that way :/

Comment: same thing  thats going on with me. we are on cs7 and cs 14. I already emailed SFDC. I'll post their response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confirmed with SF- it's a bug on thier end. no current time line for a fix.

Here's the known issue link:

http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000Su3iAAC